# Passing 3 Component Vector to openCL (java)

Tags: opencl

I am trying out openCL and I was wondering how one goes about passing a 3 component vector (float3) to an openCL program? This is probably really simple but I cannot get it to work...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **float3** is always stored in 16 bytes, not 12.  You should align all your **float3** buffers to 16 bytes, or simply use **float4**.  On the host, **cl_float3** is equivalent to **cl_float4**.